# Help with HABTM query (Rails 3)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

#group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

#join table migration
class CreateGroupUserJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :group_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :groups_users
  end
end
```

I need to make the following query:

```
@group = Group.find(:all, :include => users, :conditions => ["users count < ?", group_size]).first
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "count": syntax error: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE (users count < 2) LIMIT 1
```

I've also tried this:

```
@group = Group.where("users count < ?", group_size).first
```

But I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Group.select("groups.*, count(users.id) AS user_count").joins(:users).group("groups.id").having(["count(users.id) < ?", group_size])
```

I think that'll probably do it for you...

Comment: That gives me this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "groups_users"."group_id" = "groups"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "groups_users"."user_id" GROUP BY groups.* HAVING count(users.id) < 2`

Comment: That makes the error go away but I'm not getting the right results for my query. Is there another way of doing this? What I'm thinking of doing is just adding a users_count column to my groups model and manually incrementing it.

Comment: Try adding the `select` that I put on the query... That should give you `group.user_count` as an attribute.  What did you mean when you said "not getting the right results for my query"?

Answer (score 0):

users.count is what you need - notice you left a space. You're getting a syntax error, not some strange error.

```
@group = Group.find(:all,
                    :include => users,
                    :conditions => ["users.count < ?", group_size]).first
```

Now, if you only really wanted the first entry, you should really do:

```
@group = Group.first(:include => users,
                     :conditions => ["users.count < ?", group_size])
```

Notice I'm calling `#first`, not `#find`. `#find` will be deprecated shortly - use `#all`, and `#first` instead.

Comment: I tried both methods and I get `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError` with no further explanation.